# Database Table Column is taken as String Value in Oracle Function in JSP

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

```
Select decrypt(PRODUCT_NUMBER,'123456789') as PRODUCT_NUMBER FROM Test
```

`PRODUCT_NUMBER` is a column in Test Table and contains Encrypted data `Decrypt()` is a function created and working fine.

When i run this Sql on **Oracle SQL Developer** it gives correct Result but when i run the same on **JSP** it gives me error on Function.

In **JSP** i call this by:

```
String sql = "Select decrypt(PRODUCT_NUMBER,'123456789') as PRODUCT_NUMBER FROM Test";
rs = conn.executeQuery(sql);
```

I think it takes `PRODUCT_NUMBER as String ('PRODUCT_NUMBER')` and Not as Column Name so it gives error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

This is the Decrypt Function

```
 create or replace FUNCTION decrypt(p_raw IN RAW, p_key IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      v_retval RAW(255);
       p_key2 RAW(255);
      BEGIN
      p_key2 := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_key);
      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Decrypt
         (
          input => p_raw,
          key   => p_key2,
          which => 1,
          decrypted_data => v_retval
          );
      RETURN RTRIM(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(v_retval), CHR(0));
END decrypt;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please show the complete error, the function signature.

Comment: Decrypt Function Added and Exact Exception as Well

Comment: PRODUCT_NUMBER is the name of the column in your table and you use the same name as an alias for the result of your function. I guess that's why you get this unexpected result. Why don't you try to use another alias?

Comment: Actually That Alias is bounded with the Crystal Report and i don't think Alias is creating problem. In My Understanding the issue might be of 2 reasons.
1. RAW type as Input Parameter
2. PRODUCT_NUMBER is taken as String by SQL

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the query without apostrophes: `Select decrypt(PRODUCT_NUMBER,123456789) as PRODUCT_NUMBER FROM Test;` ? If you do, then you need to escape apostrophes in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

Query and Function both work perfect.

Actually My Co Developer had pointed the Connection to another replica instance of the DB that contained -1 in some columns so that's why it was giving error.

I reverted that and query worked like a charm.

Thanks for your time Everyone:)